# How do I make a CSR using the OpenSSL Library on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, include, openssl

I'm having difficulty with creating a CSR on iOS. How I would actually use the library to input information of our own into a CSR.

What C code would produce a saved csr file to the iOS product?

Comment: Why would that be specific to iOS?  Surely it will be the same under any platform that OpenSSL supports?

Comment: Your question is too vague to get an answer. Either ask about how to use a specific library (in which case it doesn't belong in the iOS category) or it seems you are more asking in general how you can incorporate and 3rd party C libraries into Objective C, so ask or search for that.